# KnockoutJS Validation with dynamic observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am using this plugin https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation and i am trying to validate an object that is loaded dynamically.

**Javascript:**

```
function VM() {
    var self = this;
    // This is a static observable, just to ensure that basic validation works fine.
    self.static = ko.observable();
    self.static.extend({required: true});

    // This is the observable that will be updated to my model instance.
    self.person = ko.observable({});

    // This is an handler for manual trigger.
    // I'm not even sure this is needed.
    self.a = function(){
        self.errors.showAllMessages();
        self.staticErrors.showAllMessages();
    }

    // Here i'm loading current person from somewhere, i.e. a rest service.
    self.load = function() {
        // Update observable
        self.person(new Model());

        // Define validation rules
        self.person().name.extend({required: true});
        self.person().email.extend({required: true});

        // Set person data
        self.person().name('Long');
        self.person().email('John'); 

        // Set validators
        self.errors = ko.validation.group(self.person);
        self.staticErrors = ko.validation.group(self.static);
    }
}

// Just a test model.
function Model() {
    this.name = ko.observable();
    this.email = ko.observable();
}

ko.validation.init();
var vm = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Markup

```
<ul>
    <li>1. Hit "Load"</li>
    <li>2. Hit "Show errors", or maunally change input data.</li>
</ul>
<button data-bind='click: load'>Load</button>
<br/>

<h1>This is working properly.</h1>
<input type='text' data-bind='value: static' />
<br/>

<h1>This is not working.</h1>
<input type='text' data-bind='value: person().name' />
<input type='text' data-bind='value: person().email' />
<br/>
<button data-bind='click: a'>Show errors</button>
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/qGzfr/

How do I make this work?

Comment: Have you managed to try out my proposed solutions? Are they usable for you, or do you need further help?

Comment: @nemesv I think your solutions work very well, both of them. I'm just waiting for acceptance, since someone opened a bounty on this

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed that you're not the one who have stared the bounty... so @artlung have you managed to try out my proposed solutions? Are they usable for you (they've worked well for brazorf), or do you need some further help?

Comment: @nemesv I offered the bounty just because I thought the question needed more attention. I recently used a bounty for my own question and got great help and I wanted to help a knockout.js question. I will apply the bounty to whatever post the OP wants or whatever question gets the most votes.

Comment: Which answer do you wish to get the bounty?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The validation plugin only gets applied in your bindings only if by the time when the binding is parsed by Knockout your properties are validate.

In different words: you cannot add validation to a property **after** the property was bound on the UI.

In your example you are using an empty object in `self.person = ko.observable({});` as a default value, so when Knockout executes the `data-bind='value: person().name'` expression you don't have a `name` property so the validation won't work even if you later add the `name` property to your object.

In your example you can solve this with changing your `Model` constructor to include the validation rules:

```
function Model() {
    this.name = ko.observable().extend({required: true});
    this.email = ko.observable().extend({required: true});
}
```

And use an empty `Model` object as the default person:

```
self.person = ko.observable(new Model());
```

And when calling `Load` don't replace the `person` object but update its properties:

```
self.load = function() {

    // Set person data
    self.person().name('Long');
    self.person().email('John'); 
}
```

**Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Um56/).**

Note: Knockout does not always handles well if you replace whole object like `self.person(new Model());` so it is anyway a better practice to only update the properties and not throw away the whole object.

A different solution would be to use the `with` binding because inside the `with` binding KO will reevaluate the bindings if the bound property changes.

So change your view:

```
<!-- ko with: person -->
    <input type='text' data-bind='value: name' />
    <input type='text' data-bind='value: email' />
<!-- /ko -->
```

In this case you need to use `null` as the default `person`:

```
self.person = ko.observable();
```

And in your `Load` you need to add the validation **before** assigning your `person` property so by the time KO applies the bindings your properties have the validation:

```
self.load = function() {

    var model = new Model()

    model.name.extend({required: true});
    model.email.extend({required: true});

    self.person(model);

    // Set person data
    self.person().name('Long');
    self.person().email('John'); 
}
```

**Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sV5B/).**

Comment: "you cannot add validation to a property after the property was bound on the UI." can you please share how did you get this conclusion?

Comment: @ebramtharwat from the source code of the plugin... the validation plugin is amendening the `value` and the `checked` bidings and in the `init` function it checks that the bound property is validatable or not. If the property is not validatable in the `init` then the validation plugin don't care with the property anymore: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/master/Src/bindingHandlers.js#L4-L47

Comment: If you do `value: person().name` and the value of `person` is replaced, the binding will be re-evaluated.  However, it won't call init again; just update.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work, this are the changes required:

```
<head>                                                                           
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>            
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="knockout.validation.min.js"></script>   
</head>                                                                          

<body>                                                                           
    <!-- no changes -->                                                          

    <script>                                                                     
        function VM() { ... }                           

        function Model() { ... }                        

        // ko.validation.init();                                                 
        var vm = new VM();                        
        ko.applyBindings(vm);                                                    

    </script>                                                                    
</body>
```

What was done?

- Include KnockoutJS and the validation plugin.
- Bind after the elements have been added. Remeber that HTML pages are parsed from top to bottom.

How could you tell? In the console this errors appeared:

> Cannot read property 'nodetype' of null

and

> Cannot call method 'group' of undefined

Comment: uhm there's maybe something wrong with your test code, i don't have such an error in mine

Comment: I didn't use JSFiddle, so I'm pointing out what errors could pop up. The kind of things that anyone else, facing a similar problem, should keep an eye open for (the smells). Anyway, were you able to make it work properly?